# Swift and my Idle timer implementation ( missing CGEventType )

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, appkit

In objective-c I used to implement my idle timer by basing it on the following CoreGraphics call:

```
CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState, kCGAnyInputEventType);
```

Now in swift, using the same basic call, It'd look like:

```
CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType(CGEventSourceStateID.CombinedSessionState, CGEventType.MouseMoved)
```

After examining the header files, where for instance **CGEventType** is defined, I could not find a mention to any constant that does anything in the form of which I was able to do in the ObjC implementation.

Now I could probably workaround this by looking up the value of the constant and going about it like that, but I'd strongly prefer not to. I'd rather rewrite using **IOKit** instead then. **It looks like it basically is defined as (~0)**, but like mentioned earlier, I rather not hardcode it like that.

Comment: Looks like this code wasn't annotated for Swift and that use case is broken.  I'd file a radar. That said, it looks like `CGEventType.TapDisabledByUserInput` has the same value as `kCGAnyInputEventType`.  Can you see if it works?

Comment: @BrianNickel it looks like it is giving the desired result, but it does feel rather scary to use something that seems to be going to used for something else... guess I will have to see in the future.

Answer (score 9):

Since the `~0` definition is a header #define (in CGEventTypes.h), it's unlikely to change because doing so would break binary compatibility. It should be safe to hardcode that value.

So the problem is getting a CGEventType that represents `kCGAnyInputEventType` (aka `~0`).

Here's a reasonably type-safe way of representing that:

```
let anyInputEventType = CGEventType(rawValue: ~0)!
CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType(CGEventSourceStateID.CombinedSessionState, anyInputEventType)
```